# for Loop for multiplying a value of each row with a specific column from another table based on condition in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have
table A

| NAME | STAGE | Quan | Products | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYD1234 | PROD | 4643 | A, C, T, Y | 1 | 0 |
| FGY4567 | TEST | 4739 | A, U, p, Y | 0 | 1 |
| YUD4568 | QUE | 45632 | I, Y, O, P | 0 | 1 |
| OKE4556 | STACK | 97474 | A, C, P, Y | 1 | 0 |

Table B:

| STAGE | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PROD | 10 | 5 |
| TEST | 20 | 10 |
| QUE | 30 | 15 |
| STACK | 49 | 25 |

This is the output I want.
If the stage of each row matches the stage in table B, then multiply Column A of Table A with column A of table B.

| NAME | STAGE | Quan | Products | A | B | A_STAGE | B_STAGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYD1234 | PROD | 4643 | A, C, T, Y | 1 | 0 | 10 | 0 |
| FGY4567 | TEST | 4739 | A, U, p, Y | 0 | 1 | 0 | 10 |
| YUD4568 | QUE | 45632 | I, Y, O, P | 0 | 1 | 0 | 15 |
| OKE4556 | STACK | 97474 | A, C, P, Y | 1 | 0 | 49 | 0 |

If this the code I have but it is not working as it should be.

```
for i in range(0, len(A)):
  A.loc['Stage'] == B['Stage']
  A['A_Stage'] = A['A'] * B['A']
```

Comment: You should join the tables to pair up related rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'NAME':['XYD1234','FGY4567','YUD4568','OKE4556'],
                    'STAGE':['PROD','TEST','QUE','STACK'], 
                    'Quan':[4643,4739,45632,97474], 
                    'Products':['A, C, T, Y','A, U, p, Y','I, Y, O, P','A, C, P, Y'], 
                    'A':[1, 0, 0, 1], 
                    'B':[0, 1, 1, 0]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'STAGE':['PROD','TEST','QUE','STACK'],
                    'A':[10, 20, 30, 49], 
                    'B':[5, 10, 15, 25]})
df2.columns = ['STAGE', 'A_STAGE', 'B_STAGE']
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='STAGE')
df1.loc[:,'A_STAGE'] *= df1.loc[:,'A']
df1.loc[:,'B_STAGE'] *= df1.loc[:,'B']
```